# reading excel (.xlsx) file in c#

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I am reading .xlsx file using c# like this

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
                             ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";";

var output = new DataSet();

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
{
    conn.Open();

    var dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string sheet = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [+"+sheet+"+]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OleDbDataAdapter xlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        xlAdapter.Fill(output,"School");
    }
}
```

But I am getting error at xlAdapter.Fill(output,"School");
Error is

```
The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object '+_xlnm.Print_Area+'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

I am not able to figure out that what is wrong happening in code.

Comment: what is the version of your excel file?

Comment: is there a reason for doing it this way? Can't you use some existing library for reading `*.xlsx` files?

Comment: @voo it is excel 2007 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your sheet is named `_xlnm.Print_Area`.
Try changing this line

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [+"+sheet+"+]", conn);
```

to

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ["+sheet+"]", conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define print area in your sheet "_xlnm.Print_Area" automatic added with your new sheet. Please remove print area form excel sheet or use following code

```
if (!dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("_xlnm#Print_Area"))
{    
   obj.SheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
   lst.Add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable `sheet` contains value: `+_xlnm.Print_Area+`

This `+_xlnm.Print_Area+` does not actually exists.

Thats why error is comming.

Check with that object.

Comment: from where can we see this object ?

Comment: see that , in your database 'xlnm.Print_Area' this particular table or object exists or not? and if not[thats definitely not] from where this value is comming [through debugger].

Comment: row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() is giving table name as xlnm.Print_Area but I dony know why it is giving this.

Answer (score 0):

I would check what you are getting in `row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();` values.  Alternatively, you can try OpenXML SDK: [How to: Parse and read a large spreadsheet document (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-6)

Comment: row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() is giving table name as xlnm.Print_Area but I dont know why it is giving this.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the print area in the source doc from Excel?1.Click anywhere on the worksheet for which you want to clear the print area.
2.On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click Clear Print Area.